# How can I unit test a Curses application?

Tags: unit-testing, ncurses

I'm working on a pet project to explore a bit of Curses-based programming. What's the best way to write unit tests for this? I'm thinking about the general navigation-type tests that Rails apps support (integration testing). (E.g. I want to be sure that my app can open, move down one item, increase it's priority, mark it as complete, then exit cleanly.)

For a bit more context, [my app](https://github.com/lorentrogers/todo-curses) uses the [ncursesw gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/ncursesw/). Any testing approach would be fantastic. (Ruby, C, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

The same way you test a non-curses application. Split off logic from the user interface and only test the logic.

So you wouldn't test the menu but you would test the functions that the menu items call.

Comment: Makes sense -- I suppose there's no straight-forward way to test the menus? I'm interested in making sure that things like specific key presses map to the right menus and functions. Or is this generally ignored in favor of manual QA testing?

Comment: You have to draw a line at some point and trust other developers to write reliable code.  You could mock out the menus but that becomes a real pain and of little benefit - the menu presses will very rarely change. When I am writing tests (which is anything greater than a toy app) I ignore the user interface and test what the user interface calls.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Testing best-practices have always been a gray area for me.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what aspect you want to test.  For testing *ncurses*, it has a trace feature (a compile-time option) which gives detailed information.

That is too low-level for most people, and moving up a level, the advice has been generally to write (using the library) a screen-dump function.  The library does not provide that because

- needs differ radically regarding what information should be saved (and how)
- the library provides enough capability that no *extension* to it is necessary for user applications to do this.

The *ncurses* library does provide screen dump/restore functions, but in older versions of ncurses the information is saved in binary form (less flexible in some respects than one might want).  That was revised at the [beginning of 2015](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20150321) to dump files into text format.  As a side effect, diff'ing the dumps is much simpler.

Without doing screendumps, you must rely upon either an external framework which captures the screens (and that tends to be complicated: the comment on [X/Open's page](https://www.opengroup.org/testing/testsuites/vsu5over.htm) about ["easy to use"](http://tetworks.opengroup.org/) is optimistic rather than realistic), or rely upon someone to inspect the screens and see that they look right.  I chose the screendump approach with my directory editor, making it [log commands](http://invisible-island.net/ded/ded/CHANGES.html#t19890314_u9) and added a command for doing screendumps.  Replaying the commands (and comparing successive runs) let me test for differences.

Further reading:

- [curses debugging routines](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_trace.3x.html)
- [read (write) a curses screen from (to) a file](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_scr_dump.3x.html)

Comment: Thanks - this is good info. I suppose I was wondering more about how to test integration of ncurses with my application. I edited the question to better reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a detached tmux session and capture the output:

```
tmux -u new-session -d -x 10 -y 10 -s foo
tmux send -t foo ls ENTER
sleep .5
tmux capture-pane -p
tmux kill-session -t foo
```